# How to automate testing of Canvas game using Selenium and OpenCV?

Tags: javascript, selenium, opencv, html5-canvas

I want partly automate testing of Canvas based app. To track canvas in real time and click selected objects by coordinates. Coordinates for objects should be received by comparing pictures of objects and canvas. Google doesn't give any useful info about any similar issue. (Comparing of pictures like in Sikuli isn't very useful in my case).
Can anybody help me where and how to start? Also, I want to do it using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Selenium with OpenCV like described here:

http://hacklabos.org/2019/02/python-html5-canvas-game-web-automation-example-using-selenium-and-opencv/

Import example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.tripletsandus.com/80s/80s_games/html5_galaga.htm")
def get_driver_image(driver):
    canvas_base64 = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);", a)
    cap = base64.b64decode(canvas_base64) 
    global image 
    global gray_image 
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(cap, np.uint8), 1)
```

After that you can do magic with OpenCV, for example:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/15/determining-object-color-with-opencv/